# Azure B2C securing metadata endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Does Azure B2C support custom policy metadata endpoint security using either basic authorization or certificate? The below does not appear to work as no certificate was sent to the API. I could not locate any documentation indicating that securing for metadata is supported however, I was able to locate documentation indication that RESTAPI security is supported.
[image]

Comment: what is the reason you wan to do that?

Comment: Have you got a solution or plan for this issue? If yes, you can post it as an answer then this post can be closed.